# Why there was only one episode of Black Clover?

Tags: black-clover

I have been following the manga of *Black Clover* and so far after few months, I came to know that there is an anime adaptation going on for this series.

When the first episode came, I was too excited that it started in anime but after 1 episode it's saying that the status is completed.

So why there was only 1 episode released for *Black Clover*? Is it true that status is completed? Also, are we expecting any more episodes in future?

Comment: I was looking for answers too. So only the one special episode? This Manga is too good not to animate, reminds me of Naruto "My way of magic" lol. But the anime is awesome hope they do heaps of seasons and turn out to be a popular anime series.

Answer (score 7):

Your premise of the question is wrong!

The animated episode is NOT a series, but rather a single "Special Episode" bundled with the 11th Volume of the Manga. This is mentioned as much in MAL page for the episode. Afaik, it adapts the first chapter of the Manga. [*Confirmed in Comments*]

https://myanimelist.net/anime/33950/Black_Clover

> The Episode "Black Clover" was screened at Jump Festa 2016 on November 27, 2016. The OVA was later bundled with the 11th volume of the manga, released May 2, 2017

In December 2016, there were talks about a TV adaptation of this Anime slated for release in 2017, however since only the OVA has been released, maybe they are testing the waters with the OVA release. The full series adaptation has "no official date yet"
Here is the ANN page for the same - [Black Clover by Studio Pierrot - ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-12-17/yuki-tabata-black-clover-manga-gets-tv-anime-by-studio-pierrot/.110057).
Relevant Details.

> While Viz Media's Weekly Shonen Jump Twitter account had originally stated that the anime would air in 2017, the Twitter account later redacted the statement and said the anime "doesn't have a date yet."

Thus, Black Clover's TV adaptation doesn't have a date yet, but should release in late 2017- early 2018.

**UPDATE:** As predicted Black Clover Season 1 is airing this Fall! Enjoy :)

Comment: According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC#.E3.82.A2.E3.83.8B.E3.83.A1), yes, it adapts the first chapter of the manga.

Answer (score 3):

The anime series is set to release in October 2017 sometime. (Source: [Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2017/07/14/the-black-clover-anime-series-is-coming-to-crunchyroll-this-october))

Not too far away, but still a while away. Can't wait for it though. Hope this helps.

(Side note: This show is going to blow up after its first season. The manga is already pretty big.)